# Powershell - connect to Central management Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, database-backups

I want to backup SQL Databases across many instances. To do this I want to use PowerShell. Some are SQLExpress so I cant just use SQL Agent Jobs.

I have a Central Management Server and I would like to use PowerShell to cycle through my Target Servers and Backup the Databases I require.

I have a PowerShell Script 'Backup.ps1' and I'm happy with that for the moment.

What I need is to connect to the CMS in my PowerShell Query that Calls my Script (backup.ps1).

Below is my Script (backup.ps1), My CMS is TestCMS.

*powershell C:\Backup\Tools\Backup.ps1 -serverName "GET-SERVERList -TestCMS" -backupDirectory 
"C:\Backup\Backups" -daysToStoreBackups 7 >> C:\Backup\Logs\%date%.log*

What is the correct Syntax to Connect to the CMS and Loop through my Targets?

All help is Appreciated.

Cheers,

R

Comment: Apologies, The Query in the question is not my backup.ps1 script. its the PowerShell Query Calling the Script .

Comment: What is the role of the Central Management Server. You can run the backup script from any client and backup database. Can you post the script of backup.sp1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save list of servers in a text file e.g servers.txt which contain the names of all database servers/instances like:

```
 server1
 server2
 server3\instance
```

Run the backup script :

```
  Get-Content $server.txt | 
  backup -serverName $_ -backupDirectory "C:\Backup\Backups" -daysToStoreBackups 7
```

Comment: Thank You M.Hassan, I'm new to Powershell but experienced with SQL, I already have a CMS so I was thinking that Powershell could connect to my Registered Server and Run against my Targets. Thanks again for your help. Far easier to do it this way.